# Project cannot be built in XCode10.3, Apple match-o linker error with swift libraries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.3

I had a iOS project written with Swift. This project built & runs nicely in XCode 9.x, however when I try to build it with XCode 10.3, the build failed, with this warning/error displayed:

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreData'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
```

Searched for a few solution but it's all happening to Obj-C project that using Swift Pods.
Whilst my project is Swift.
Did anyone have any solution for this so I can build project properly?